Dealing with closet odor
I need some advice on dealing with a persistent odor issue in my duplex. My house was originally a single-family home, later converted into a duplex. My flat is on the first floor, and I have an upstairs neighbor with an aging dog. Unfortunately, the dog has been having accidents on the carpets and floors upstairs.
For the summer, the upstairs vents have been closed, so the smell isn't as pervasive throughout my flat. However, the strongest smell of animal urine and dampness is coming from a closet that has a stairwell. This closet seems to be the most affected because the floor above the stairwell has nothing but a door separating it, and the smell permeates through.
I don't use this closet often, but I'd like to repurpose it for additional storage. I was considering taping up a plastic drop cloth beneath the floor/above the stairs to contain the smell. My landlords are aware of the situation and plan to replace the carpet upstairs with a more cleanable surface, but I'm unsure when this will happen.
In the meantime, I'm looking for effective solutions to mitigate the smell. Damp Rid and air sanitizer sprays haven't worked. I'm open to any suggestions that could help improve the situation.
Thanks in advance for your help!


[

I don't know if it'll work completely, but a ~$20 USB rechargeable ozone generator, such as sold for keeping the inside of refrigerators odour-free, could help.
Using a small ozone generator would mean you could keep it on permanently, as opposed to a larger unit that is intended for a one-off application of ozone in a room (or car).
Note that ozone can be be harmful: Wikipedia: Ozone Health Effects. If you open the door and get too much of a chlorine-like smell then it's overdone it. Open the windows and go outside for a few minutes while the ozone dissipates. I am not a medical professional.

Okay, this is very interesting! I will look into this more. Thank you for your input.
